# Spring Cloud Kinesis Binder Consumer Group Settings to avoid duplicate records processing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I am using spring cloud kinesis binder and having issues in using the consumer group

Here is my application config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        sample-binder:
          destination: sample-destination
          group: sample-group
          content-type: application/json
        sample-binder-2:
          destination: sample-destination-2
          group: sample-group-2
          content-type: application/json
```

Kinesis has 2 Shards and 2 application instances are currently running.

The problem I see is that both the application instances are processing all records which means the consumption of duplicate records.

Can someone help as to what I am doing wrong and how can I achieve equal distribution of records processing over many application instances and the right configuration to achieve ordering?

Comment: I read we can use kpl-kcl-enabled flag which uses KCL which supports it. However, I would be interested to see a sample code since I tried to add the flag and it fails on leaseCorordinator after 20 attempts

Comment: Further debugging into this when trying to use kpl-kcl-enabled=true, I noticed that rhe billingMode on LeaseManager class is throwing null pointer exception here
`request.setBillingMode(this.billingMode.name());` because the BillingMode is not set. I know this is not binder question but can some check how to setup BillingMode on LeaseManager or use default constructor which seems to be deprecated now